# How can I apply physics to a SKShapeNode in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In the following example, there are three things on the screen:

1. `ball` (a `SKShapeNode`)
2. `spriteContainer` (a `SKSpriteNode` that contains `ball2`, a `SKShapeNode`)
3. `box` (a `SKSpriteNode`)

Why does `ball` fall out of view? Does a `SKShapeNode` need to be inside a `SKSpriteNode` to have physics properly applied to it?

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        SKColor * warmRed = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.99 green:0.41 blue:0.25 alpha:1.0];
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.backgroundColor = warmRed;

        //falls out of view
        SKShapeNode * ball = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
        CGMutablePathRef ballPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddArc(ballPath, NULL, size.width-40, self.size.height/2, 20, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
        ball.path = ballPath;
        ball.lineWidth = 2;
        ball.fillColor = warmRed;
        ball.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        ball.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:20];
        [self addChild:ball];

        //lands on bottom of screen
        SKShapeNode * ball2 = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
        CGMutablePathRef ball2Path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddArc(ball2Path, NULL, 0, 0, 20, 0, M_PI*2, YES);
        ball2.path = ball2Path;
        ball2.lineWidth = 2;
        ball2.fillColor = warmRed;
        ball2.strokeColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        CGSize spriteContainerSize = CGSizeMake(40,40);
        CGPoint spriteContainerPosition = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2);
        SKSpriteNode * spriteContainer = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:spriteContainerSize];
        spriteContainer.position = spriteContainerPosition;
        spriteContainer.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:spriteContainerSize];
        [spriteContainer addChild:ball2];
        [self addChild:spriteContainer];

        //lands on bottom of screen
        CGSize boxSize = CGSizeMake(40,40);
        CGPoint boxPosition = CGPointMake(boxSize.width, size.height/2);
        SKSpriteNode * box = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:boxSize];
        box.position = boxPosition;
        box.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:boxSize];
        [self addChild:box];


    }
    return self;

}
```

Screenshot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/164157126/example.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you don't set a position for the node which falls off the screen, but set a position for the other two nodes you create.

The default position of a node is 0,0. Your ball will appear at the bottom left of the scene, and since it is over the edge body you defined, will fall off immediately.

Set the ball's position appropriately so that it does not intersect the edge of the screen, and the ball will not fall off.

Comment: You should also set the categoryBitMask and collisionBitMask, appropriately, to ensure the nodes and the edge collide correctly.

Comment: @CodeMonkey Not needed in the current context.

Comment: Yes, but in the future it will likely matter. I'm pretty sure this isn't the final game.

Comment: @duci9y I'm setting the starting position of `ball` in `CGPathAddArc`, and you can see it is within the bounds of the screen in this [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/164157126/example.jpg). It starts out at the same place as the other nodes, but just keeps falling off the bottom of the screen :(

Comment: @user3885233 No, that's incorrect. Read the documentation for the `path` property. The path should be defined in the coordinate system of the node, not the parent node. Also read up about the `showsPhysics` of `SKView` and enable it to see what physics bodies are actually created. Also read up on `accumulatedFrame` and log it when you create your ball.

Comment: @CodeMonkey That won't solve the problem. And that's not needed here either.

Comment: @duci9y you were right. I set the `x` and `y` values in `CGPathAddArc` to 0, and made a new `CGPoint` for the `ball.position` property and everything is working now.